# PHP Pass array between two functions

Tags: php, arrays, function

I currently have 2 functions; i need to read one array that's inside one of the functions from the inside of the other function:

```
function a(){

 foreach ($options as $option){ // $options is a variable from function b()
  // here goes a really long loop
 }

}

function b(){

 $options[] = array(
   'key1' => 1,
   'key2' => 2,
   'key3' => 3,
  );

 function a(); // run function here?
}
```

My php file is gonna have multiple copies of what we call "**function b()**". And inside each **function b()**, i wanna run **function a()**, but use the array content that's inside the **function b()**.

**function a()** contains a loop that's always the same but really long, i just want to keep my code as short as possible instead of copying **function a()** inside each **function b()**.

This is probably really easy but i've been struggling with this issue for a long time now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return the array from `b()` and then pass it as a parameter to `a()`

```
function a($options){
    foreach ($options as $option){ 
      // here goes a really long loop
    }
}

function b(){
   $options = array(
       'key1' => 1,
       'key2' => 2,
       'key3' => 3,
   );
   a($options);
}
```

Comment: forgot to mention that i must run function a() inside function b(). function b() is in my scenario a tab on a webpage. Got another solution?

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Could you not simply pass it as a function argument?

```
function a($options){
    foreach ($options as $option){ // $options is a variable from function b()
        // here goes a really long loop
    }
}

function b(){
    a(array(
        'key1' => 1,
        'key2' => 2,
        'key3' => 3,
    ));
}
```